# How to show forgot password option in text input layout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to show forgot password option within textInputLayout shown in the screenshot. Also want to set click action. How this can be achieved?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you will get answer from here..

http://codevscolor.com/2016/08/android-material-design-tutorial-10-password-visibility-toggle/

Comment: Link broken. "NOT FOUND - You just hit a route that doesn't exist... the sadness."

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a textview inside Edittext, Both withing relative layout. That way you can have clicklisteners for textview too and align textviews whereever you like.

like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hint="Password" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Edittext"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Edittext"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="forgot Password..?" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but i want this in textInputLayout.

Comment: @NiteshMishra Did you try changing the TexView in the above code to TextInputLayout..?

Comment: @NiteshMishra and also Is there any reason you are using textInputLayout...?

Comment: I have the same question as @NiteshMishra If developers want to keep the behaviour of the material design with the hint sliding above the input on focus, they'd need to use textInputLayout.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create create custom background for whole layout.
And make transparent the background of Edittext. Here is example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:text="Forgot Password"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I took a View for line below edittext. you can change its color according to you.